# How to stop cocos2d accumulating animation delta

Tags: ios, cocos2d-iphone

I have a weird situation where if my app goes to the background and comes back to the foreground the animations are accumulated somehow and applied super fast. e.g. a CCRotateBy catches up for the time the app was in the background and spins the sprites really fast.

My app delegate has the correct application state handling I think..

```
- (void)applicationWillResignActive:(UIApplication *)application {
    [[CCDirector sharedDirector] pause];
}

- (void)applicationDidBecomeActive:(UIApplication *)application {
    [[CCDirector sharedDirector] resume];
    [[OALAudioSession sharedInstance] forceEndInterruption];
}

- (void)applicationDidReceiveMemoryWarning:(UIApplication *)application {
    [[CCDirector sharedDirector] purgeCachedData];
}

-(void) applicationDidEnterBackground:(UIApplication*)application {
    [[CCDirector sharedDirector] stopAnimation];
}

-(void) applicationWillEnterForeground:(UIApplication*)application {
    [[CCDirector sharedDirector] startAnimation];
    [[OALAudioSession sharedInstance] forceEndInterruption];
}

- (void)applicationWillTerminate:(UIApplication *)application {
    CCDirector *director = [CCDirector sharedDirector];

    [[director view] removeFromSuperview];

    [director end];
}

- (void)applicationSignificantTimeChange:(UIApplication *)application {
    [[CCDirector sharedDirector] setNextDeltaTimeZero:YES];
}
```

What is causing this to happen?

Comment: which version are you using? There was a similar bug [last year](http://code.google.com/p/cocos2d-iphone/issues/detail?id=1435), which was fixed for 2.1.

Answer (score 0):

Its one of the problem we face with cocos2d 2.0.

TEMP_FIX: I used manual pause for animation.

```
-(void) applicationWillResignActive:(UIApplication *)application
{
    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] postNotificationName:@"AppEnterBackground" object:nil];

    if( [navController_ visibleViewController] == director_ )
        [director_ pause];
}



//In game layer

-(void)onEnter
{
    [super onEnter];
    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self  selector:@selector(AppEnterBackground:) name:@"AppEnterBackground" object:nil];

}

-(void)onExit
{
    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] removeObserver:self name:@"AppEnterBackground" object:nil];
    [super onExit];
}

-(void)AppEnterBackground:(NSNotification*)notif
{
    [self pauseSchedulerAndActions];

    [mHero pauseSchedulerAndActions];

    for(MyCoin *coin in mCoinArr)
    {
       [coin  pauseSchedulerAndActions];
    }
}
```

Similar way you can resume.

Comment: I just tried this and it seems to work. -(void) applicationDidEnterBackground:(UIApplication*)application {
 [[CCDirector sharedDirector] stopAnimation];
    [[CCDirector sharedDirector] pause];
}
 
                   -(void) applicationWillEnterForeground:(UIApplication*)application {
 
    [[CCDirector sharedDirector] stopAnimation];
    [[CCDirector sharedDirector] resume];
    [[CCDirector sharedDirector] startAnimation];
}

Comment: I tried same now..and not working for me...COCOS2D_VERSION 0x00020100

Comment: ok..may be this is resolved in new version...no worries...already our app is live in app store...:)

Comment: and updating cocos2d is a hassle ;)